# gcc compiling c++ without any flags

Tags: c, gcc, c++11, g++

## Context

Recently, under my ubuntu 12.04, I worked to get a new `g++` in order to compile `-std=c++11`.
But it seems some modification has affected `gcc` as well:

## Problem

The fact is that now, when I compile with `gcc`, it seems it directly (and without any flags) compile C++ programmes when I want to compile C programmes:

For example:

```
$ gcc assem.c
assem.c: In function 'int main()':
assem.c:6:13: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   char* k = "aa";
```

#### assem.c

```
void f() {}
int main() {

  int a = 0;
  double c = 0;
  char* k = "aa";

  f();
}
```

## Some tests on my gcc

The version:

```
$gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

alias on gcc:

```
$ alias gcc
bash: alias: gcc : non trouvé
```

which on gcc:

```
$ echo `which gcc`
/usr/bin/gcc
```

possible flags left in my env:

```
$ env | grep FLAG
#nothing
```

## So

Any idea what's the problem?

## Edit

`gcc assem.c -v` clearly indicate there's g++ involved:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE assem.c -quiet -dumpbase assem.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase assem -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccoeLOQ4.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) version 4.8.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/.
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) version 4.8.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 227d7ccf008db5ae401be7ddcc6b4746
assem.c: In function 'int main()':
assem.c:8:13: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   char* k = "aa";
             ^
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccWfpqbX.o /tmp/ccoeLOQ4.s
GNU assembler version 2.22 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/ccWfpqbX.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

#### As requested by Jonathan

```
$ ls -li /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]
2633166 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct 10 14:15 /usr/bin/g++ -> /etc/alternatives/g++
2624623 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct  8 11:38 /usr/bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc
$ls -Lli /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]
2650954 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 775944 Jun  5  2013 /usr/bin/g++
2650954 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 775944 Jun  5  2013 /usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc assem.c -Wstrict-prototypes
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
assem.c: In function 'int main()':
assem.c:6:13: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   char* k = "aa";
```

## Solution

Thanks to [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) and [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/): there was the problem:

```
$ ls -li /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]
2633166 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct 10 14:15 /usr/bin/g++ -> /etc/alternatives/g++
2624623 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct  8 11:38 /usr/bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc
$ls -Lli /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]
2650954 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 775944 Jun  5  2013 /usr/bin/g++
2650954 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 775944 Jun  5  2013 /usr/bin/gcc
$  ls -l /etc/alternatives/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Oct 10 14:15 /etc/alternatives/gcc -> /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```

and the real solution was to doing this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 <priority>
```

Comment: Didn't get your problem. `gcc` can compile a C file without any flags also.

Comment: yep, but that's my problem: without any flags, it compile c++ when i want to compile c

Comment: On what basis did you deduce that!!

Comment: string are c++ and this is an c++11 error if i'm not wrong...

Comment: OK; now what are the other two lines of code in your actual `toto.c` file? The error is reported on line 8 but the erroneous code is on line 6 of what you show.  You wrote `Toto.c` in the question at one point; are you sure you don't have `Toto.C` (because a `.C` suffix indicates C++).  You're right about the error being a C++ error rather than a C error.

Comment: If you want to prove that it compiles as C++, use a C++-only feature in the file such as `class`.

Comment: What exact compilation command are you using? With what compiler flags.

Comment: @interjay done, and... well it works fine... so there g++ really involved in my compilation....

Comment: Please post the *actual* command you run, and the *actual* errors you get. Don't edit them to make them look prettier, you're quite possibly removing relevant content from them.

Comment: @hvd that's just an error of mine.. i copy pasted the wrong output, i'll just restart from 0

Comment: @CollioTV Your current question again claims to run `gcc toto.c -v`, and claims to receive errors from `assem.c`, so it's quite clear that you either edited the command, or the command's output.

Comment: ok...so i just modified all the name to be assem.c... no more error now, but i think i'll reolve it by myself because the name of one file seem to bother you more that teh real error...

Comment: @CollioTV Hold your horses sir. There is no error in code. http://ideone.com/FUb2Ej. Everyone is telling you you have strange things going on. **You compile one file but get the error from a different one.** Also, I suggest you seek help on AskUbuntu or *nix help page, because **something is certainly not right on your end.** From our side, the problem is not reproducible. Sersiously, the code is fine, it's the system setup most probably. EDIT: And now you hide real problem with your edit, because you think you know better where it is. I give up. You are obstructing people helping you.

Comment: Let's try to eliminate the improbable: what do you get from `ls -li /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]`?  If there are symlinks involved, then also show `ls -Lli /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]`.  Add the information to the question.  I'm wondering if the `gcc` binary is actually a copy of, or link to, the `g++` binary, somehow.  Pretty unlikely, except that it would account for the eccentric behaviour you're seeing. You could also try the option `-Wstrict-prototypes`; it is not valid with `g++` but is with `gcc`.

Comment: :nos the actual question is now exactly what i have, @jonathan, it's done

Comment: Did you `aptitude install build-essentials gcc g++` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't have aptitude, should i do it with apt-get?

Comment: Half-done; there are symlinks involved, so I asked you to include the `ls -Lli` output, but that doesn't seem to be in the question (yet).  The error message with `gcc -Wstrict-prototypes` is instructive; it strongly suggests that `gcc` is somehow pointing at the C++ compiler and not the C compiler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry forgot to copy past, there is your answer^^

Comment: And there is _your_ answer: the inode numbers (that's from the `-i` and is the first number on the output) shows that both `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` are pointing to the same file, inode number 2650954.  So, they're both the C++ compiler.  I suggest uninstalling both compilers and reinstalling.  That should sort things out.

Comment: @CollioTV If you now check ls -l /etc/alternatives/gcc , you might find where it points to, which is likely to g++

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks! i'll do it (you sir are great! sorry to be a bit upset><) if you wanna post an answer (which could help over people who might get my problem, i'll approve it!)

Comment: @nos... there was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer*</sup>

Let's try to eliminate the improbable — what do you get from:

```
ls -li /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]
```

If there are symlinks involved, then also show the output from:

```
ls -Lli /usr/bin/g[c+][c+]
```

I'm wondering if the `gcc` binary is actually a copy of, or link to, the `g++` binary, somehow. Pretty unlikely, except that it would account for the eccentric behaviour you're seeing. You could also try the option `-Wstrict-prototypes`; it is not valid with `g++` but is with `gcc`

<sup>*[…time passes…]*</sup>

The error message with `gcc -Wstrict-prototypes` is instructive; it strongly suggests that `gcc` is somehow pointing at the C++ compiler and not the C compiler.

<sup>*[…more time passes…]*</sup>

And there is your answer: the inode numbers (that's from the `-i` and is the first number on the output) shows that both `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` are pointing to the same file, inode number 2650954. So, they're both the C++ compiler.

I suggest uninstalling both compilers and reinstalling. That should sort things out.

Alternatively, if you have `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` (and it is a different file from `/usr/bin/g++-4.8`), you could change `/etc/alternatives/gcc` to point to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.8` without doing a complete reinstall.  On the whole, though, I recommend uninstall and reinstall.  If this got messed up, what else also got messed up.

---

Please note that it is best to keep everything you show in your question completely straight so that there are no inconsistencies.  Failing that, edit everything very carefully so that there are no inconsistencies.  It complicates life for those trying to answer the question if there are internal inconsistencies — we don't know what can be trusted and what can't be trusted.

Your problem was unusual — very unusual.  I did not expect the improbable to be what was happening, but then, as [Sherlock Holmes](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes) is reputed to have said, "How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?"

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 <priority>` there was my solution (less dangersous than reinstalling all)

Comment: Do you have any idea how the alternatives link got messed up?  I agree with your solution (except I've not used `update-alternatives`, but it is doing what I suggested as an alternative).  If you don't know how it got messed up and if you still get oddball results, I do recommend the uninstall and reinstall.  If what you've done works (and it may well do so), then you're home and dry much more easily.

Comment: the precedent intern got this computer (and session) while i was at a meeting, i think i know where the problem come from...